# SaveAs always overwrites existing file

Tags: python, excel, com, activex, excel-2013

I am trying to use the Excel 2013 com interface to use the SaveAs function. Everything is working pretty well except that every SaveAs operation will overwrite the existing file.

Related Questions:

[Python and Excel: Overwriting an existing file always prompts, despite XlSaveConflictResolution value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373955/python-and-excel-overwriting-an-existing-file-always-prompts-despite-xlsavecon)

[Why can't I “save as” an Excel file from my Python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730428/why-cant-i-save-as-an-excel-file-from-my-python-code)

This is how I instantiate Excel:

```
import win32com.client
excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = 1
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('D:\\somefileXYZ.xls')
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
```

The file 'D:\somefile.xls' already exists.

Using the Microsoft [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214129.aspx) it should work like this:

```
wb.SaveAs('D:\\test.xls', win32com.client.constants.xlWorkbookNormal, \
                            None, None, False, False, win32com.client.constants.xlNoChange, \
                            win32com.client.constants.xlOtherSessionChanges)
```

but it just overwrites the existing file.

Using this it should throw an exception, but this also just overwrites the existing file.

```
wb.SaveAs('D:\\test.xls')
```

If I remove this line `excel.DisplayAlerts = False` Excel asked me if I want to overwrite the existing file. But I want to do it automatically.

I did the same at another computer with Excel 2007 and everything was working fine.

Comment: This may not be what you desire, but you could just use a `os.path.isfile(input_file_path)` before you save to see if the file already exists.

Comment: I could do that but I want to save the file if the workbook is the given file and nothing is overwritten.